# Finding basis B and C of a Linear Transformation WRT B and C

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

new to this site, so please forgive any formatting errors. :)
I have come across a practice problem for a midterm, but there is no solution, so I'm not sure what I am supposed to do for the question:

> Given a linear transformation $T: V \to W$, we know that $[Tx]C = [T][x]B$. 
>    Find a basis $B$ of $V = P_1$ and basis $C$ of $W = P_2$ such that $$T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
>   and $T: V \to W$ is $T(p(x)) = \frac{d}{dx} p(x) - xp(x)$.

I know that since $B$ is a basis for $P_1$, we can take $B = \{1, x\}$. This transformed would be $\{-x, 1-x^2\}$ for $B$. Then, we know that $[T] = [[Tb_1]C [Tb_2]C]$ tells us that
$$
    [Tb1]C = 1C_1 + 0C_2 + 0C_3 \Rightarrow C_1 = -x\\
    [Tb2]C = 0C_1 + 1C_2 + 0C_3 \Rightarrow C_2 = 1-x^2
$$
So $C = \{-x, 1-x^2, ?\}$. I can't seem to figure out what to do to find ?. Any insight would be great. Thank you. :)